# fatal error, unable to load plugins "sudo error in linux mint"

Tags: linux, pip, sudo

I am facing an issue when I am installing python packages:

The error is:

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin `sudoers_policy'
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

Comment: How did you install the Python packages?

Comment: i had  installed  using pip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file has the wrong permissions, it should ONLY be writable by the owner, and its currently not.

To confirm that run:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
```

When the permissions are correct, that should print '-rw-r--r--':

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 316768 Jul  4  2017 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
```

To fix the issue (as long as you are root) run:

```
sudo chmod 644 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
```

Comment: i was execute "sudo chmod 644 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so"
but return same error.. please help

Comment: walter-cejas : you are going to need root access to modify sudoers.so. If you do not then you will need to contact whoever administers that node to have them make the change.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ su root     # log in to root
$ chmod 644 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so      #change read/write permission to owner
$ chown -R root /usr/lib/sudo      #change owner of sudo directory to root
```

if $ su root doesn't work, instead try:

```
$ pkexec su
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a same issue, i can fix it. In my case Ubuntu 19.10

Open your terminal and type below simple code

```
sudo -i
```

open another terminal and check below command.

```
sudo apt update
```

Hope, this will help you